# How to show error message in my android webview app when no internet

Tags: java, android

I am working with an android webview application. I use my url succesfully in my app and it works only if an internet connection is available. But I want to show some messages when there is no internet connection. How can I do this?

```java
package com.echoedev.rackstk;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://example.com/");
        setContentView(webView);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a whole guide about reading connectivity state and reacting to changes: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/reading-network-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your internet connection is available before loading the page

```
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        setContentView(webView);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);


      if(isNetworkAvailable(this)){

        webView.loadUrl("https://example.com/");

         } else {


      Toast.makeText(this,"NO internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
```

Check the connection

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            return capabilities != null && (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) || capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET));
        } else {
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I did not understand what you mean

Comment: what is cm and how do i import it. It is showing up as null

Comment: is connectivity manager . I have updated the code